# avoid loading jquery multiple times while calling bootstrap modal/dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I've created a theme in xpages (which has jquery and bootstrap files). I created a bootstrap modal and i'm loading another page in body of the modal dynamically. 
Following is the main page code where i'm calling bootstrap modal

```
x$("#{id:test}").modal("show")
```

Following is my custom control code (which is like subform in mainform)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoParseOnLoad="false"
dojoTheme="false" dojoForm="false">





<xp:div id="test">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="role" value="dialog"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>

    <xp:div>

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div>

                <button type="button" class="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    ×
                </button>
                <h4>

                </h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>

                <div styleClass='modal-footer'>

                </div>

        </div>

    </xp:div>
</xp:div>
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

});]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[

    // Fill modal with content from link href
    var id="#{javascript:var id=compositeData.dialogid; getClientId(id)}"


        x$(id).on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
            alert('fires immediately when the show instance method is 
  called')
            $(this).find(".modal-body").load('./LoginAsAdmin.xsp');
        });

        x$(id).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
          //var test = #{javascript:print('==========server side')};
          alert('fired when the modal has been made visible')
        })

        x$(id).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
          alert('fired immediately when the hide instance method has been 
 called')
        })

        x$(id).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
          alert('fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the 
 user ')
           $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        })

        x$(id).on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
          alert('fired when the modal has loaded content')
        })


]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

</xp:view>
```

Now when i call the dialog on click of a button i get numerous client errors saying multidefine, file loaded multiple times etc. This is because jquery loaded twice when i load the actual page and it loads again when i invoke bootstrap modal. is there a way where i can load jquery single time in the page without using iframe inside the modal?

Comment: How exactly are you "loading another page in body of the modal dynamically."? Show us that code. What all are you "loading", are you just getting the full html of the other page? Off hand, you'll likely want to load just the content you're after and not the whole other page, or load the page into an iframe, but we need to see what you're actually doing.

Comment: i've added actual code in my question. i'm loading another page in the body of the modal on "shown.bs.modal" event. it is difficult to add only content of the form. because forms has many sections which will be hidden based on few conditions.

Comment: There is high probability that loaded modal page will be broken because of scripts generated for Xpage. I advise you to use dynamic content component and custom controls instead

Comment: I would recommend to use the `xe:dialog` control from the Extension Library. That integrates a lot better with XPages.

Comment: @Frantisek +1 for for suggesting dynamic content component it actually works it doesn't load js libraries second time when i load dialog.

Comment: @Mark yep that could be an option but want to try bootstrap modal

Answer (score 0):

The [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function has several different signatures (ways you can call it and pass different parameters to do different things)

If you look at the section

Loading Page Fragments

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that is fetched:
>
> `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`

This seems to be what you likely want. So you could do something like:

`$(this).find(".modal-body").load('./LoginAsAdmin.xsp #my-form-containg-element');`

If the form you're trying to get and display has dependancies (js or css) that are outside the target element, like in the head tag, you'll either need to include those resources on the parent page as well or load the target url into an iframe instead of a div and display that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. my problem is that i was able to load another page/section of the page in the modal. Issue was with the jquery file which is loading twice (one when i load the actual page and another when i call the modal which inturn loads another page in the body). This is because theme (xpages) will be called twice when each page loads. is there a way where i should load dialog independent of the parent page? or how to avoud loading jquery file multiple times

Comment: @gkreddy either of the methods I outlined will do just that.

Comment: even when you use load method js libraries load second time when the dialog loads. i think using dynamic content component of xpages will work. Thank you for your suggestions.